# How to implement nested RecycleView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a nested recycle view i read several post online, but i am still having a difficult time. This is what i did so far, i created a main layout which contains my main Recycle view, i then created the main recycle view row item. And populated it by creating an adapter and implementing it in my main activity.  Secondly, i crated a layout with my child recycle view as well as the child recycle view row item. The problem arises when i am trying to access this recycle view, i am unsure as to how to go about doing this? I was able to access my parent recycle and implement the adapter in my main activity, but i am not sure as to how to access my child recycle view. Could someone assist me?

```
**Parent Recycle View**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </RelativeLayout>

**Parent Recycle View row**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view_home"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <ImageView

                    android:id="@+id/image_view_movie"
                    android:layout_width="130dp"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layout_mov"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/image_view_movie"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Mission Impossible"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_genre"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Action,Comedy..."
                        android:textSize="12sp" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    </RelativeLayout>

**Child RecycleView**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_movie_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Movie Category"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/home_recycler_view_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_movie_category"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/activityMainDivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home_recycler_view_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:background="#31C7C7CC" />


    </RelativeLayout>

**Child recycle view row**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"

        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/newsThumbNail"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.448"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dangerous fire is out of control at 24 and park"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/newsThumbNail"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/newsThumbNail"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newsThumbNail" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/newsBody"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="Some text is here"


                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/newsTitle"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/newsTitle"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newsTitle" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


**Parent Adapter**

    public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<DataModel> userMessagesList;


        public HomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataModel> userMessageList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.userMessagesList = userMessageList;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.inner_recycleview_row, viewGroup, false);
            return new MessageViewHolder(view);
        }

        //Loads data into views
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

            //            viewHolder.senderTextView.setText(message.getMessage());

            viewHolder.senderTextView.setText(userMessagesList.get(i).getName());

            viewHolder.receiverTextView.setText(userMessagesList.get(i).getAge());


        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return userMessagesList.size();
        }


        //links up ui elements
        static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView senderTextView, receiverTextView;


            public MessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                senderTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_genre);
                receiverTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);

            }


        }

    }

**Main Activity**

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private RecyclerView messagesRecycleView;


        private ArrayList<DataModel> messageList;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            messageList = new ArrayList<>();


            initRecycleView();

            populateArray();



        }



        public void populateArray(){

            DataModel dataModel1= new DataModel("Bob","18");

            messageList.add(dataModel1);




        }


        //set up RecycleView
        public void initRecycleView() {
            messagesRecycleView = findViewById(R.id.rv_main);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            //linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
            messagesRecycleView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            HomeAdapter homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(MainActivity.this, messageList);
            messagesRecycleView.setAdapter(homeAdapter);

        }
    }




public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<DataModel> userMessagesList;




        public NewsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DataModel> userMessageList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.userMessagesList = userMessageList;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_feed_row, viewGroup, false);
            return new MessageViewHolder(view);
        }

        //Loads data into views
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

            //            viewHolder.senderTextView.setText(message.getMessage());

            viewHolder.senderTextView.setText(userMessagesList.get(i).getName());

            viewHolder.receiverTextView.setText(userMessagesList.get(i).getAge());





        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return userMessagesList.size();
        }


        //links up ui elements
        static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView senderTextView, receiverTextView;


            public MessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                senderTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsBody);
                receiverTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);

            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: I think you need to create an adapter for it as well and initialize the adapter and recycler view inside your parent's bindviewholder. It is fairly simple, let me know if you'll need code as well.

Comment: I edited my quesiton and  created the adapte (NewsAdater) for my child recycle view Could you show me what code i need to add in my parent adapter?

Comment: this is wrong way to implement. You should use only one recycleview and another recycleview in 1st recycleview's item. And check-in position 0 you should add you another recycleview and it's code. So your app can run easily and smoothly.

Comment: What do you mean by use another recycle view in 1st recycleview item?

Comment: You should go for Groupie library!